# dropdown menu jquery toggle items

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem with a jQuery dropdown menu. My code:

```
$('.item-active, .item').click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('item-active');
    if($('h3').hasClass('item-active')) {
        $(this).siblings().css( 'display', 'block' );       
    }   

    $(this).toggleClass('item');    
    if($('h3').hasClass('item')) {
        $(this).siblings().css( 'display', 'none' );    
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="item-active">item 1</h3>
    <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="item">item 2</h3>
    <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="item">item 3</h3>
    <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
```

All I need is to have the menu toggle when the related `h3` is clicked. Also, only one item may be active at the same time (the rest of the descriptions should be hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can simply use `removeClass()` to remove the `.item-active` class from all elements before toggling it on the the one which was clicked.

Also note that you can simplify the JS code to just amending the class and leave CSS to hiding/showing the `.item-desc` by using the `+` sibling operator. Try this:

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  $('.item').not(this).removeClass('item-active');
  $(this).toggleClass('item-active');
});
```

```css
.item-active {
  color: #C00;
}
.item-desc {
  display: none;
}
.item-active + .item-desc {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3 class="item item-active">item 1</h3>
  <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="item">item 2</h3>
  <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="item">item 3</h3>
  <div class="item-desc">Lorem Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfectly, didn't knew it can be that simple :) thanks!

Comment: `$('.item').removeClass('item-active');` instead of  `$('.item').not(this).removeClass('item-active');` also works. Isn't it?

Comment: That works, but stops the toggle functionality working on the item you clicked. Your way means that you can not hide the content of the active `h3` on successive click - you'll only ever be showing it